# emacs - error: Key sequence

Tags: emacs

I am getting errors when I try to add this to my ~/.emacs file:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "ss" 'split-window-vertically)
```

I get this error:

> error: Key sequence s s starts with non-prefix key s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that there is already a command bound to `s` (specifically, `evil-substitute`), which means you could not get to you `ss` binding because the first `s` would invoke `evil-substitute`.  You can undefine the `s` by setting it to `nil` and then bind `ss` as you already have it:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "s" nil)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "ss" 'split-window-vertically)
```

(If you want to know what commands are bound to which keys, you can use `M-x describe-key SOMEKEY` or `C-h k SOMEKEY`.)